# Как защитить код сборки visual studio 2017 (winforms) и информацию которую она обрабатывает

Tags: клиент-сервер, шифрование, защита

Подскажите от декомпиляции и получения паролей злоумышленником можно защитить свое приложение? В приложении планирую хранить не только пароль к фтп, а также и ключ шифрования текста. Может быть есть относительно несложный (для начинающего) способ безопасной передачи информации.

Answer (score 0):

Способа защитить хранимый в приложении пароль от FTP нет и быть не может - т.к. этот пароль передается в открытом виде по сети, и для его перехвата достаточно возможности установки сниффера на машине-клиенте.

Answer (score -1):

Если пишите на C#, то исходный код довольно просто получить. Код можно обфусцировать (см. обфускация). Но сама идея изначально неправильная
[Тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/966308/nuzhno-v-prilozhenii-spryatat-parol-kak) подобное обсуждение